# PHP - Laravel - Getting average directly from Eloquent and not having to loop through the results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm building a survey platform and I need to get the average answer rate of the survey.
What I'm currently doing is retrieving all the questions and then dividing times viewed and times answered. Is there a more efficient / less resource consuming method by calculating average on the DB and not looping through thousands of results?

Here is my working code right now that takes forever:

```
    $total_showed = 0;
    $total_answered = 0;

    $total_queries = Query::where('client_app_id','=', $app_id)->get();

    foreach ($total_queries as $app_query) {
         $total_showed = $total_showed + $app_query->showed;
         $total_answered = $total_answered + $app_query->answered;
    }
    if ($total_showed > 0) {
        $total_arate = round(($total_answered / $total_showed) * 100, 1);
    } else {
        $total_arate = 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you do count instead of get you'll get the count back. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
`$total_showed = $total_queries->sum('showed')`
`$total_answered = $total_queries->sum('answered')`

since $total_queries is a collection you can use it's sum method
see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sum
this would be mre efficient I think

Comment: Does the ```sum``` method queries the DB again or is it handled by PHP?

Comment: no it doesn't it's in  the Collection class ... check the documentation for this class

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can go into Raw SQL:

instead of:

```
$total_queries = Query::where('client_app_id','=', $app_id)->get();
```

use something like:

```
$total_queries = Query::select(DB::raw('SUM(showed) as counter, SUM(answered) as answered'))
              ->where('client_app_id','=', $app_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this aggregate function avg(); like this

```
$price = DB::table('orders')->where('finalized', 1)
                ->avg('price')
```